# Python3 on Debian: Serial fails while init

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, debian, pyserial

I'm trying to use [this Python script](https://github.com/PX4/Firmware/blob/master/Tools/px_uploader.py) to program a Pixhawk on a Debian, but it keeps getting stuck. On another machine with Ubuntu it works well. I made sure that I am member of group *dialout*. I successfully used the QGroundControl application on the Debian to connect to the device.

I localised that the error occurs in `serial.Serial()`:

```py
class uploader(object):
    '''Uploads a firmware file to the PX FMU bootloader'''

    def __init__(self, portname, baudrate_bootloader, baudrate_flightstack):
        print("DEBUG: init")
        print("DEBUG: init port")
        print("DEBUG:",portname)
        print("DEBUG:",baudrate_bootloader)
        try:
            self.port = serial.Serial(portname, baudrate_bootloader, timeout=2, write_timeout=2)
        except:
            print("Who knows")
```

console output:

```sh
DEBUG: init
DEBUG: init port
DEBUG: /dev/serial/by-id/usb-3D_Robotics_PX4_FMU_v2.x_0-if00
DEBUG: 115200
Who knows
```

If I try to catch the exception with:

```py
except (OSError, serial.SerialException, serial.SerialTimeoutException):
```

this line seems to be ignored.

What is happening here? And how can I solve this?

---

```sh
$ ll /dev/ttyACM0 /dev/serial/by-id/usb-3D_Robotics_PX4_FMU_v2.x_0-if00 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        13 Feb 12 23:04 /dev/serial/by-id/usb-3D_Robotics_PX4_FMU_v2.x_0-if00 -> ../../ttyACM0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Feb 12 23:04 /dev/ttyACM0
```

---

As explanation:
The original script runs into an endless loop and via placing `print` calls I found that this code snipped may cause this:

```py
class uploader(object):
    ...
    def __init__(self, portname, baudrate_bootloader, baudrate_flightstack):
        # Open the port, keep the default timeout short so we can poll quickly.
        # On some systems writes can suddenly get stuck without having a
        # write_timeout > 0 set.
        # chartime 8n1 * bit rate is us
        self.chartime = 10 * (1.0 / baudrate_bootloader)

        # we use a window approche to SYNC,<result> gathring
        self.window = 0
        self.window_max = 256
        self.window_per = 2  # Sync,<result>
        self.ackWindowedMode = False  # Assume Non Widowed mode for all USB CDC
        self.port = serial.Serial(portname, baudrate_bootloader, timeout=0.5, write_timeout=0.5)
        self.otp = b''
        self.sn = b''
        self.baudrate_bootloader = baudrate_bootloader
        self.baudrate_flightstack = baudrate_flightstack
        self.baudrate_flightstack_idx = -1
```

I found, that a print behind `self.port = serial.Serial(...)` will not occur. There also is no error message or crash. A crash nay not happen because the call of the uploader is inside a try:

```
 try:
     if "linux" in _platform:
         ...
         up = uploader(port, args.baud_bootloader, baud_flightstack)
     elif ...
 except Exception:
     # open failed, rate-limit our attempts
     time.sleep(0.05)

     # and loop to the next port
     continue
```

I'm not sure, but it seems that this is a issue of Python pyserial which only occurs on Debian. I can not reproduce this on other OS. But on other Debian.

Comment: Using a catch-all except block is rarely a good idea.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with python. I also try it one by one (`except OSError:`, `except serial.SerialException:` and `except serial.SerialTimeoutException:`)

Comment: if you remove the try/except statements entirely, what error do you get in your output?

Comment: The original code do not have a try/except. I put a `print` at the end of `def __init__` but it wont reached, so I go backward and found that the last call was `serial.Serial()`. But no further error output or crash happen.